# Print out the whole raw http request

Tags: python, http, request, hmac, bottle

how do I get the whole raw http request in the python framework bottle?

I need something like this:

```
GET\n
myurl.com\n
/\n
attribute=value
&att2=value2
```

I need this to sign my http api requests

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I can tell from [the docs](http://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/api.html#bottle.LocalRequest) you can't get the data in raw format.

What you can do is reconstruct it using `bottle.request.data` and `bottle.request.headers`. That may be enough for your purposes.

Comment: bottle.request.method and bottle.request.query is my solution thanks!

Answer (score 3):

If you just want to print the request you can do the following:

```
headers_string = ['{}: {}'.format(h, request.headers.get(h)) for h in request.headers.keys()] 
print('URL={}, method={}\nheaders:\n{}'.format(request.url, request.method, '\n'.join(headers_string)))
```